# Count Acute, Right and Obtuse triangles from n side lengths

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, complexity

**Problem Statement**: We have \$N\$ sticks. The size of the \$i\$th stick is \$A_i\$. We want to know the number of different types of triangles created with each side from a single different stick. Calculate the number of acute triangles, right triangles and obtuse triangles.

**Input Format**: The first line contains \$N\$. The second line contains \$N\$ integers. The \$i\$th number denotes \$A_i\$.

**Constraints**:

- For full score: \$3 \le N \le 5000\$
- For 40% score: \$3 \le N \le 500\$

**For all test cases**:

- \$1 \le A[i] \le 10^4\$
- \$A[i] \lt A[i+1]\$ where \$1 \le i \lt N\$

**Output Format**: Print 3 integers: the number of acute triangles, right triangles and obtuse triangles, respectively.

**My Solution**: My code runs in the given time for small \$n\$ (~500). It will work for large \$n\$ (~5000) but I get time limit exceeded error on the Online Judge.

```
using System;

namespace CodeStorm
{
    class Triangles
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] A_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] A = Array.ConvertAll(A_temp, Int32.Parse);
            int[] A_sq = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                A_sq[i] = A[i] * A[i];
            }

            int n_m_2 = n - 2;
            int n_m_1 = n - 1;

            int acute = 0, right = 0, obtuse = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n_m_2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < n_m_1; j++)
                {
                    int k = j + 1;
                    int AiPlusAj = A[i] + A[j];

                    while (k < n)
                    {
                        int squareSum = A_sq[i] + A_sq[j];
                        if (AiPlusAj <= A[k])
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (squareSum > A_sq[k])
                        {
                            acute++;
                        }
                        else if (squareSum < A_sq[k])
                        {
                            obtuse++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            right++;
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(acute + " " + right + " " + obtuse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code runs perfectly and finds the possible triangles.

**Input:**

```
6    
2 3 9 10 12 15
```

**Output:**

```
2 1 4
```

The possible triangles are:

> Acute triangles: 10−12−15, 9−10−12
>
> Right triangle: 9−12−15
>
> Obtuse triangles: 2−9−10, 3−9−10, 3−10−12, 9−10−15

I want to know a more efficient way to approach the problem so that I can get it executed in the given time limit for \$n\$ (~5000). After I tried to find the complexity, I came up with \$O(n^3)\$. I am not good with complexities. I might be wrong. I would like a more efficient way for the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Sort your sticks by length; square them when already sorted. Then replace the innermost loop with 3 binary searches. In pseudocode,

```
        max_obtuse = upper_bound(A[j:n], A[i] + A[j])
        max_right = upper_bound(A_sq[j:n], A_sq[i] + A_sq[j])
        max_acute = lower_bound(A_sq[j:n], A_sq[i] + A_sq[j])

        obtuse += max_obtuse - max_right
        right += max_right - max_acute
        acute += max_acute - j
```

That reduces the execution time from \$O(n^3)\$ to \$O(n^2\log n)\$.

EDIT:

In the sorted array below, values marked as `-` are strictly less, and values marked as `+` are strictly greater, than `X`:

```
    -----XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX++++++++++
         ^                ^
         |                This is upper bound of X
         This is lower bound of X
```

Comment: Sir I am new to algorithm. I didn't understand the pseudo code. What do you mean by upper bound and lower bound binary searches. I am sorry if I sound weird. But I am not able to understand the code.

Comment: @AmanAhuja See edit.

Comment: First of all thank you so much. That helped me a lot. It improved my code. The code was submitted for a problem on hackerearth. Earlier I cleared 8 out of 16 cases(due to TLE). With your help I could do another 4. The 4 remaining cases are still showing a TLE error. Is there any way to reduce the execution time further. I am using C#. Is it a problem with the language. The execution time has to be within 3s. Thank you anyways.